# I failed to use `mvn spring-boot:build-image` and remote docker daemon on win10

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud-function, spring-native

spring-boot-starter-parentm 2.4.4

My project is on win and docker is on another linux. Even if I put the built jar in the corresponding directory ( /home/iserver/spring)on linux, it cannot be successful

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-native.version>0.9.1</spring-native.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <docker>
                        <host>tcp://{remoteDockerIp}:2375</host>
                    </docker>
                    <sourceDirectory>/home/iserver/spring</sourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

while `mvn spring-boot:build-image`

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image (default-cli) on project demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image failed: Executable jar file required for building image
```

log

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image (default-cli) @ demo ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) host = tcp://192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG]   (f) docker = org.springframework.boot.maven.Docker@3a2b1f24
[DEBUG]   (f) excludeDevtools = true
[DEBUG]   (f) excludes = []
[DEBUG]   (f) finalName = demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) builder = paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny
[DEBUG]   (f) env = {BP_NATIVE_IMAGE=true}
[DEBUG]   (f) image = org.springframework.boot.maven.Image@1314ccc1
[DEBUG]   (f) includeSystemScope = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includes = []
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ E:\WorkSpace\code\java\spring\demo\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@350b3a17
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDirectory = E:\home\iserver\spring
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Opening connection {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] Connecting to /192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] Connection established 192.168.13.232:10118<->192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] Executing request POST /v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Atiny HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> POST /v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Atiny HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 0
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/{remoteDockerIp}
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:28 GMT
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request GET /v1.24/images/docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:3b2a9a7ace49a36b2762b5f2d3a7524f8b58cc41854e47f1e3cec448eba8319c/{remoteDockerIp} HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> GET /v1.24/images/docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:3b2a9a7ace49a36b2762b5f2d3a7524f8b58cc41854e47f1e3cec448eba8319c/{remoteDockerIp} HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/{remoteDockerIp}
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:28 GMT
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:3b2a9a7ace49a36b2762b5f2d3a7524f8b58cc41854e47f1e3cec448eba8319c'
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request POST /v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Frun%3Atiny-cnb HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> POST /v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Frun%3Atiny-cnb HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 0
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/{remoteDockerIp}
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:44 GMT
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request GET /v1.24/images/docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:d4923f52c0db29257e19708d557051a5be4385e8128ce2431665d75ae84b8a1a/{remoteDockerIp} HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> GET /v1.24/images/docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:d4923f52c0db29257e19708d557051a5be4385e8128ce2431665d75ae84b8a1a/{remoteDockerIp} HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/{remoteDockerIp}
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:44 GMT
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:d4923f52c0db29257e19708d557051a5be4385e8128ce2431665d75ae84b8a1a'
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request POST /v1.24/images/load HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> POST /v1.24/images/load HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/x-tar
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/{remoteDockerIp}
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:44 GMT
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.10.1
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-5cbe5692dbc4.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request DELETE /v1.24/volumes/pack-layers-pmwnnbewwy?force=1 HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> DELETE /v1.24/volumes/pack-layers-pmwnnbewwy?force=1 HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:44 GMT
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request DELETE /v1.24/volumes/pack-app-ntswwmmvkx?force=1 HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> DELETE /v1.24/volumes/pack-app-ntswwmmvkx?force=1 HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:44 GMT
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375] can be kept alive indefinitely
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] CookieSpec selected: default
[DEBUG] Auth cache not set in the context
[DEBUG] Connection request: [route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://192.168.13.178:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[DEBUG] Executing request DELETE /v1.24/images/pack.local/builder/gpkywzhokr:latest?force=1 HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> DELETE /v1.24/images/pack.local/builder/gpkywzhokr:latest?force=1 HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 192.168.13.178:2375
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_282)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Api-Version: 1.40
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/{remoteDockerIp}
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Docker-Experimental: false
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Ostype: linux
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Server: Docker/19.03.5 (linux)
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 01:34:44 GMT
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 226
[DEBUG] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

=================

If I don’t set /home/iserver/spring

> Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image (default-cli) on project demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 100

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in tiny builder
`<builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>`
If I use `paketobuildpacks/builder:base`, it's okay

It's ok to use `paketobuildpacks/builder:0.1.58-tiny